# Query last element in array from json structure in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

Let's say that we have the following

```js
{ "items" :
    [
        {"id": 1},
        {"id": 2},
        {"id": 3}
    ]
}
```

How can I get the last element from the array in the given json structure? Getting the first one seems not that complicated

```sql
SELECT t.column->'items'->0 AS elem
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  other_column = 20;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you always have a simple uniform JSON structure? Because a simple, inelegant trick would be to find a substring.

Comment: The json structure will need more information than the one I provided. It was more illustrative than anything else, hoping to have an easy answer. I am interested on how you could handle it using substring. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Regex's in your SQL on strings, and treat your JSON as a string: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html - if you know that the JSON ends with }]}, you can find the element that precedes that - it's messy, and PostgreSQL has better ways of handling it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something like this should get the last element of your example:

```
SELECT t.col->'items'->(json_array_length(t.col->'items')-1)
FROM   tbl t
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6a01d/8) showing this in action...

Comment: For me, the function name had to be caps for it to work (windows, perhaps?) JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH/JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH

Answer (score 4):

In Postgres 9.5+ one can now use negative subscripts to achieve this.

For your case above, getting the last element could be achieved by:

```
SELECT t.column->'items'->-1 AS elem
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  other_column = 20;
```